# Bad Request (400) in TestRestTemplate exchange method GET

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I am running Spring boot test with TestRestTemplate.

Succeeded in testing get request for `List<Member>`. To test a get request for Member throws bad request 400. I followed similar pattern to `List<Member>`, have read many answers here on Stackoverflow where I got the hint for `List<Member>`, it throws a bad request. The `HttpEntity` is set to `JSON`. `Member` has `id`.

Find below  `MemberController`, `MemberControllerTest`, and `HttpEntity` methods for setting headers

```
@GetMapping(path = "/api/member/{member-id}")
public ResponseEntity<Member> getMemberById(@PathVariable(name = "member- 
         id", required = true) Long memberId) {
    Member member = memberService.findById(memberId);
    if (member != null) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(member);
    }
    return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
}

@Test
@Transactional
public void getMemberSuccessful() throws Exception {
    HttpEntity<Object> member = getHttpEntity("{\"member-id\": \"2\"}");

    ResponseEntity<Member> response = 
    template.exchange("/api/member/{member-id}", HttpMethod.GET, member,
            Member.class, "member-id");

    Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCode().value());

}

private HttpEntity<Object> getHttpEntity(Object body) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    return new HttpEntity<Object>(body, headers);
}
```

Expected result is test to run and return status code 200 but I get this error

> java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<200> but was:<400>   at
>   org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)     at
>   org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)   at
>   org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:645)    at
>   org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:631)
>   com.thankgod.controller.MemberControllerTest.getMemberSuccessful(MemberControllerTest.java:151)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add the urivariable at the end of the `exchange()` method:

```
template.exchange("/api/member/{member-id}", HttpMethod.GET, null,
            Member.class, 2);
```

TestRestTemplate won't read it from `HttpEntity` object

Comment: It worked. I have been thinking HttpEntity would feed in the value since that was possible for postForEntity. I need to learn more on HttpEntity, headers, RestTemplate and TestRestTemplate. But is there any way I can pass in json into exchange method?